# Will any browsers not submit a blank form field?

Tags: php, html

When processing form input in PHP, can I safely assume that all form fields in the submitted form were sent through, or are there some browsers that will not even pass along blank fields?

Sorry if this is a common question, I just can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: @MikeW, empty text fields (even `<input name=foo>` where no user input has taken place) are sent by conforming browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember one rule: Don't trust anything out there!

Do not assume anything check alway everything which comes from a user and validate that values.

But yes normally it is send.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should assume that, just because not all requests to your PHP code will always come from the form you crafted; your code should be prepared to handle the case where someone is just making off-hand requests that may not look at all how you expected them to.

Comment: The way I look at it, if a user is submitting malicious code or trying to send form values without actually filling out the form as is intended, my DB query just won't go through and the page won't look right to them...but that's not my problem, right?

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear from the question what the potential side-effects were of "assume that all form fields in the submitted form were sent through", so I just elaborated the general principle: don't trust, validate.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well, as somebody who is likely more experienced than me, would you agree with my previously presented paradigm given that you've got a bit more insight now?

Comment: As long as your code makes sure that omission of one or more fields cannot cause any harm, then it only becomes a UX question. I would generally recommend trying to fail gracefully, rather than just dropping everything off the end of the Earth and saying "Well, you didn't do it the way I expected, so too bad for you, bucko." But there's definitely a lot of room to wiggle around in the space of what it means to "fail gracefully", and your business logic will usually dictate that as much as anything you are told on SO by random people. :)